# The filesystem and Inversion of Control / Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

From within a controller, we are allowed access to read the contents of a file from file system, but we are not allowed access to values in `appsettings.json`. I understand the value in separating one's code from system specific implementation details, but does that mean that file dependencies should be only accessed through injection? I'm looking to understand the best practices of IoC/DI.

In this example, for contrast, what if I saved my recipient's email address in a file instead of appsettings? (I'm not suggesting that it would be a good idea).

```
string body = string.Empty;
//allowed
string filePath = Path.GetFullPath("Templates/ToEnrollee.html");

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    body = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
 //not allowed
string recipient = Configuration.GetValue<string>("recipient");
```

Comment: "...why is it OK to ..." who told you that's ok?

Comment: How would you inject a file? rofl. You use DI for dependencies, a file well... is no dependency. Options can be loaded into an model and injected, files well can't

Comment: For reading from a file, you're specifically depending on an implementation. You're using StreamReader. If you wanted to follow IoC principles, you would depend on an abstraction, not an implementation. Fortunately for reading files, you can use the [System.IO.Abstractions](https://github.com/tathamoddie/System.IO.Abstractions) library.

Comment: *“what if I saved my recipient's email address in a file instead of appsettings?”* – Apart from the fact that the `appsettings.json` is obviously also a file, there is nothing wrong with it. It’s just that you would have to read that file over and over, or create some caching mechanism and which point you would also need to incorporate dependency injection so you can access it. And then you might want to allow different file formats, and multiple sources, and support changing the file without restarting… and suddenly you have implemented `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` yourself…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would never use the built-in FileSystem classes directly (Path, File, Directory, etc). I would *always* look to abstract them.

A very simplistic example could be:

```
public interface IFileSystem
{
    string ReadAllText(string path);

    //... other file system operations
}

public class WindowsFileSystem : IFileSystem
{
    public string ReadAllText(string path)
    {
        return File.ReadAllText(path);
    }
}
```

At the time you are defining your dependencies you can swap this out for an implementation that suits the environment the application is running in.

This would allow you to inject implementations to fully control usage of the filesystem and help with unit testing.

Comment: I agree with this approach, but it's abstracting a dependency not Injecting it.

Comment: Perhaps it's poorly worded, but I meant that you can _inject your abstracted implementations_.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? There's a [solid well tested library](https://github.com/tathamoddie/System.IO.Abstractions) that has the interfaces for you.

Comment: Because I find that the best way to learn is to try these things for yourself rather than relying on always _having_ to find a library that has done the work for you without really understand what they are doing... and besides... writing code is much more fun that integrating someone else's library ;)

Comment: It's fine to learn and have an idea of how things work under the hood. But when it's time to actually get something done in a production environment, taking the time to write your own library instead of using something that's been battle-tested and can be fixed by someone outside your team if a bug does arise is ridiculous.

Comment: Of course and i'm totally not disagreeing with you that you would use something that is tried and tested, but knowing how things work under the hood allows you to make a much more informed decision on which library to use for particular scenarios... I'm not suggesting that one would re-invent the wheel for no good reason (and my comment about it being "more fun" was just tongue in cheek) - I don't think that just putting "use this library" makes for a very good answer to someones question around how something works.

Answer (score 2):

Reading a file from within the services of the application is *runtime behavior*. It is normal for services to have runtime behavior.

However, reading configuration settings is *configuration*. This is normally done one time at application startup in order to tailor specific settings of the composed application.

What's more is that reading config settings directly from services couples the service directly to the config file. This is the main problem - there is no way to swap those settings for testing or if you need to override them for some reason (conversely, you can put some simple logic at application startup to override any settings in the file).

On the other hand, if your service reads from a file it is only tightly coupled if you don't pass in the path or an open stream to the file. Allowing the path to be passed in means you can test that service without being coupled to a specific file on the file system. It is even better if you can pass in a stream (keep in mind that `Stream` is an abstract class) so it can be swapped with a `MemoryStream` or other type of stream if `FileStream` isn't directly supported. Of course, it is also important to separate other business logic from the code that reads/writes files so business logic can be tested without a dependency on the file system at all.

Comment: I would argue the same about *any IO*.  Reading a config is the same as Reading a file.  If an application decides to run on Azure and you want to replace all your system IO to azure file storage you're screwed unless you've also abstracted system IO.